# SSL Medium Strength Cipher Suites Supported in Amazon Linux

Tags: security, ssl, openssl, centos

I ran a nessus scan on an Amazon Linux server and it showed the result as 
"SSL Medium Strength Cipher Suites Supported".

I have modified the following settings in /etc/httpd/ssl.conf

```
SSLProtocol -ALL -TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2 -SSLv3
SSLProxyProtocol all -SSlv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
#SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH 
SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 !EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA !RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA !ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA !DES-CBC3-SHA !ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA !RC4-MD5 !RC4-SHA"
```

I have restarted the httpd service and rerun the nessus scan. The above change to the ssl.cof didn't work. The scan again shoed the following results ,

- SSL Version 2 and 3 Protocol Detection SSL Medium Strength Cipher
- SSL RC4 Cipher Suites Supported (Bar Mitzvah)

I doubt that I need do some changes in openssl configuration also. If yes, where and how should I configure Openssl ciphersuites?

I have verified that I am changing the correct ssl.conf.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you restart your server? Did you check with https://testssl.sh/ also?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I have restarted only the httpd service and not the server completely. Will do it and share you the status.  But why do we need a restart of a server? Any special reasons?

Comment: Apache read its configuration when it starts or reloads (`apachectl graceful`). If you do neither, your changes in the configuration files will not be taken into account. Ok; sorry; maybe I was not clear enough in my "restart your server" sentence server was referring to the Apache process (webserver) not the whole box. Sorry if that was misleading.

Comment: I have restarted apache but nessus returns still the same results

Answer (score 0):

Please configure the your ssl.conf file as below:

```
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
SSLHonorCipherOrder On
SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:!3DES
```

After that restart httpd service: `service httpd restart`

The "SSL Medium Strength Cipher Suites Supported" vulnerability can be showed according to your tcp port.

If you see this vulnerability on the tcp/443 port, it should be resolved after made configuration above. Otherwise you can see it on the tcp/4444 port that uses by openDJ or somethink like that.

In this case, remove **3DES** from the list of legacy algorithms that located under your java security path.

- On JDK 8 and earlier, edit the `<java-home>/lib/security/java.security`
  file and remove **3DES_EDE_CBC** from the **jdk.tls.legacyAlgorithms**
  security property.
- On JDK 9, edit the `<java-home>/conf/security/java.security` file and
  remove **3DES_EDE_CBC** from the **jdk.tls.legacyAlgorithms** security
  property.

Answer (score 0):

SSL hardening is not an easy topic but there are many good resources online. I suggest you have a read at how to harden Apache on this link: https://cipherli.st/

This website gives you a ready-to-use secure configuration that goes beyond just the cipher suite and it also provides you with more information about it, if you're curious to understand.

**For Apache, for instance, the recommendation is:**

```
SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
SSLHonorCipherOrder On
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload"
Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
# Requires Apache >= 2.4
SSLCompression off
SSLUseStapling on
SSLStaplingCache "shmcb:logs/stapling-cache(150000)"
# Requires Apache >= 2.4.11
SSLSessionTickets Off
```

With the first line being the recommended cipher suite. They provide a description of this configuration at https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Strong_SSL_Security_On_Apache2.html

Don't forget to **reload apache configuration** when done!